# Optim() making Paremeters equal to each other in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a matrix where I would like to estimate 4 values:

```
M = [ var1    corr    0]
    [ corr    var2    0]
    [  0       0      0]
```

Basically, the matrix has two variances and a correlation in the position M[1,2] and M[2,1] which should be equal. To this end, I wrote a function for optim as follows:

```
M <- matrix(c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,0,0,0),3,3,byrow=TRUE)

objf <- function(pars, model, estimate = TRUE) {

    model$M[is.na(model$M)] <- pars[1:4]

    if (estimate) {
        -logLik(model)
    } else {
         model
    }
}
```

However, when I run my code the output for the two correlation values is different, so I was wondering if there is a better way to write my code such that I have M[1,2] = M[2,1]. I think using the line `model$M[is.na(model$M)]` is the issue but I'm not sure how to write the code better, so if anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your objective function to have only 3 parameters and replace

```
model$M[is.na(model$M)] <- pars[1:4]
```

with

```
model$M[is.na(model$M)] <- pars[c(1,2,2,3)]
```

An illustration

```
M <- matrix(c(NA,NA,0,
              NA,NA,0,
              0,  0,0), 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
pars <- 1:3
M[is.na(M)] <- pars[c(1,2,2,3)]
M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    0
[2,]    2    3    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: Hmm actually I take that back, I think this seems to be okay after all, thanks!